# Replace a string with array values in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I searched on Google for some options to replace a string with some array values in Twig, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Is it possible to replace a string with array values in Twig?

I tried to code something like this:

```php
{% set foo = ['.JPG', '.BMP'] %}
{% for Item in ProductImage %}
<tr>
  <td class="lo-stats__image">
    <img class="border rounded" src="http://5.12.82.223/ftp/images/{{ brand_number }}/{{ Item.PictureName|replace('.jpg': foo) }}">
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In clasic PHP is working this way:

```
$photoarray = array('JPG', 'BMP');
str_replace($photoarray,"jpg", $image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments of your filter call is slightly incorrect, it should be something like this:

```
{% if Item.PictureName ends with '.jpg' %}
    <img class="border rounded" src="http://5.12.82.223/ftp/images/{{ brand_number }}/{{ Item.PictureName|replace({'.jpg': '.JPG'}) }}">
{% endif %}
```

As described in the replace filter [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html):

> replace¶
>
> The replace filter formats a given string by replacing the
> placeholders (placeholders are free-form):
>
> {{ "I like %this% and %that%."|replace({'%this%': foo, '%that%':
> "bar"}) }}
>
> {# outputs I like foo and bar    if the foo parameter equals to the
> foo string. #}
>
> {# using % as a delimiter is purely conventional and optional #}
>
> {{ "I like this and --that--."|replace({'this': foo, '--that--':
> "bar"}) }}
>
> {# outputs I like foo and bar #}
>
> Arguments¶
>
> ```
> from: The placeholder values
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, pal. I didn't think of this option.